# practice sql explanation

Tags: sql

http://studybyyourself.com/seminar/sql/exercises/8-3/?lang=en

> Please provide data about all employees whose salary is higher or equal to the average salary of employees working in the same department (regardless if employees have left the company or not). Required attributes are last name, first name, salary and department name.

```sql
SELECT emp.Last_name, emp.First_name, emp.Salary, D.Name

FROM Employee AS emp

INNER JOIN Department AS D ON emp.Department_id = D.ID

WHERE emp.Salary >=

  (

   SELECT AVG(e.Salary)

   FROM Employee AS e

   GROUP BY e.Department_id

   HAVING e.Department_id = emp.Department_id

  )
```

Can anyone please help explain the solution?  Specifically, what does the 'having' clause do in this case that allows the sub-query to work?  I get stuck up until that point without the having clause and I expectedly get the 'subquery returns more than 1 row' error but I am not sure how the having clause is fixing the problem.

Comment: Please include the problem description and solution as plain text, not as a link.

Comment: please read and follow [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question. the link is also useless since there is no actual code and leave us no code for any debugging. this question is currently not answerable.

Comment: The `HAVING` acts as a correlation for the subquery against the outer query. So you only ever get one row because it's grouped by `e.Department_id` and the correlation is also against that column. Incidentally, this problem can also be solved by using a window function, which is usually more efficient